# Script to find files with a specific extension but NOT containing specific text

Tags: find

I am trying to write a script that basically searches recursively using find (or another method to) to find all files ending with *.p or *.w but does not contain sysvars.i or preprocess.i

Is find the best command to use?

Comment: Do you mean that the **name** should not contain "sysvars.i" etc. or there should be no such strings in **the content** of the files?

Answer (score 5):

You can combine the actions of `find` and `grep` to accomplish this:

```
find /search/path/ -type f \( -name '*.p' -or -name '*.w' \) \
    -exec grep -L -e 'sysvars.i' -e 'preprocess.i' {} +
```

Let's break that down.

- `find /serch/path` returns all files in the specified path. Next wee need to narrow that down starting with the things that will eliminate the most matches first to save time checking the other things later.
- `-type f` returns only files. If you happened to have directories matching the file name pattern, we don't want to send them to `grep`.
- `\( [expr1] -or [expr2] \)` creates an either/or match so that find returns files that metch either expr1 or expr2 but there is no reason it has to match both. The parenthesis help separate this *or* group from the rest of the matching options that are actually *and* requirements.
- `-name '*.p'` and `-name '*.w'` are pretty obvious, return files matching those name patterns.
- `-exec command {} +` will run the specified command and any arguments with the `{}` bit replaced with arguments for each file matched by the rest of the `find` command. The `-exec` function is preferable to using `xargs` or piping to a loop  because it handles quoting and file name issues so well.
- `grep` is used to search for a pattern in the specified files.

  - `-L` is used to return just a list of file names that do not have matches
  - `-e 'PATTERN'` is specified twice to list the two search strings you did not want to match.

Comment: That didn't work gave me find {-H} -{L} path-list predicate list

Comment: Now tried to use the following code:-

Comment: @colin: Can you answer @rozcietrzewiacz's comment on your question so that we know if we understood your question correctly or not? Did you read the explanation for this command and did it all make sense? Perhaps you see something in there that isn't actually what you wanted to accomplish, hence the empty results. Also, are you sure there are files to be found that match all those criteria? Try taking out just the `-v` on the grep and see if that returns the files that do have that string. Try removing the entire `-exec` section to see what find is returning as far as files to be searched.

Comment: I've never done anything more with grep before, than the simplest of simple patterns; `sed` has always done what I needed,  so I'm on unfamilar ground with its options, but on my Ubuntu system, `find -l -v -e` doesn't work, and I believe it will only work when **every** line in a file matches the pattern... However `grep -L -e 'sysvars.i' -e 'preprocess.i'` works...

Comment: *@Caleb:*  Here is link to the [test script](http://paste.ubuntu.com/656486/). It shows the `grep` version and the test results I get.

Comment: @fred and Caleb: `grep -L` is not at all the same as `grep -lv`. `grep -L` finds files that have no matching line. `grep -lv` finds files that have at least one non-matching line.

Comment: @Gilles: Yes that finally dawned on me when fred's test case failed for me too. When I originally wrote this answer I only checked against test files with one line! Thanks both of you.

Answer (score -1):

It's possible to build complex boolean expressions of find tests:

```
find . \( -name '*.p' -or -name '*.w' \) -and \
  -not \( -name 'sysvars.i' -or -name 'preprocess.i' \)
```

Posix compliant options names are `-a`, `-o` and `!` instead of `-and`, `-or` and `-not`.

If you need to look for strings inside files contents, then you must use `find` along with `grep` (for example).

Comment: The short form of `not` is `-!`, not `!`. The latter refers to command history (by shell expansion).

Comment: Ok, so you must be looking for `sysvar.i` and `preprocess.i` inside file contents, or the filtering would be useless :-)

Comment: I think the OP was wanting to find files that did not **contain** those strings. This command doesn't make any sense because matching for the names `*.[pw]` would already exclude the names `(sysvars|preprocess).i`.

Comment: @Caleb What might have sense, though, is `find . \( -name '*.p' -or -name '*.w' \) -not \( -name '*sysvars.i*' -or -name '*preprocess.i*' \)`

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz: No, not if used alone. You may escape it with `\!` if you wish. "The POSIX standard specifies parentheses '(', ')', negation '!' and the *and* and *or* operators ('-a', '-o')".

Comment: Ah, true - `\!` is the way to avoid shell interpretation and `-!` seems to be just an alias for the negation.

Comment: Voting for removing this answer and the following discussion if the OP's question turns out being related with file contents.

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz `-!` and `-not` are aliases for `!` in GNU find. The portable way to write the negation operator is `!`.